# Selectable alternative to JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, swing

**Backgorund info**:

I have a buddy of mine in the Navy, and he wanted to know if I could whip him up a small app that would calcualte when he has his guard duty, because apparently counting on a calendar is hard. I used `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` to give him the output of the dates. Here's how I'm doing that.

```
GregorianCalendar knownDate = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);

GregorianCalendar[] futureDates = new GregorianCalendar[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    futureDates[i] = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);
    futureDates[i].add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,10*(i+1)); // duty every 10 days
}
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Jakes duty dates:").append(newline);
for(GregorianCalendar d : futureDates) {
    sb.append(months[d.get(Calendar.MONTH)]).append(" ");
    sb.append(d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append(newline);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sb.toString());
```

The 'only problem' is you can't select the text that is displayed. He'd like to select it for IM and email, because what's the point in only being half lazy, right? (Only problem is in quotes because I have a feeling he'll scope creep this to death... haha)

**My question**:

Is there a "one-line solution" to making a selectable `showMessageDialog`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to build on trashgod's answer. While he suggested using a `JList`, I'm instead using a JTextArea (which gives the kind of selection I need.)

Here's what I'm doing:

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(sb.toString());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text);
```

And it's working like a charm!

================================================

After a little experimentation I did this:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for(GregorianCalendar g : futureDates) {
    String m = months[g.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
    String d = String.valueOf(g.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    model.addElement(m + " " + d);
}
JList jlist = new JList(model);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jlist);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jlist.getSelectedValue());
```

And the second box displayed what I had selected on the first one. I was really impressed with that. Now granted, this isn't the functionality I was going for (the top section is) but that doesn't make it any less awesome! :-)

Comment: That's the ticket! Many components support this kind of [DnD](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html).

Comment: Yeah it's pretty cool. And to your credit, JList's definition of selection is probably far more common than what I was referring to!

Comment: BTW, the `DefaultListSelectionModel` lets you do the usual actions like select all and multiple selections.

Comment: Super cool! I'm going to keep this in mind, as I'm doing some swing for a more serious project. This was just a one-off thing for a buddy, but I'm so glad I was able to learn something very useful by it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add the dates to a `DefaultListModel`, create a `JList`, and pass the list to `showMessageDialog()`. It's more than one line, but the selection copies to the clipboard using the platform's `copy` keystroke.

```
private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        GregorianCalendar knownDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        knownDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10 * i);
        dlm.add(i, df.format(knownDate.getTime()));
    }
    JList list = new JList(dlm);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);
}
```

Comment: For convenience, you could automate the copy to the system clipboard in a list selection listener.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but that's not the select I meant. This is certainly cool, it allows me to select one of the rows, but I mean... select the entire block of text for copying to the clipboard.